# Android emulator "launch from snapshot" for Froyo

Tags: android, emulation, launch, snapshot, android-2.2-froyo

Can I use "launch from snapshot" from my `SDK`&`AVD manager` for `Android` 2.2 (Froyo)?
Right now, the option is implicit and I am not being able to check the option.

If it is possible for froyo, than how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to edit your existing `AVD` and enable snapshots.